# What is the most efficient way to insert a number into an ordered array?

Tags: j

Inserting numbers into a sorted array is a very common need.

Mathematica stack exchange for reference. Its priority queue appears extremely fast.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224249/best-way-to-insert-element-into-an-ordered-list-at-the-correct-position

For J:
Using the built in sort `/:~y` where `y` is the sorted array -
examples:   `/:~ y,45.3` or `/:~ y,3 6 67.7`
would be the first choice.

Quicksort and bubblesort are much slower.

For a single insert rotating the number into the sorted list -

```
insert=: 4 : 0
 NB. insert x into ordered array y
 where=: x (< i. 1:) y
 z=: (($y)-where)|.(where|.y),x
)
```

is around 2.5 times faster on `y=.i.10000000` than `/:~y`

anything faster?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that anything is faster than what the first comment under that other question suggested?

Comment: 1) I found no significant difference between the two methods; behcnmarking with `timespacex` in `j901` 2) `z =: where ({.,x,}.) y` seems slightly better.

Comment: Any idea of what Mathematica's "priority queue" might be about? "If you have v12.1, there's no need to ever call Sort if you can incrementally add your values to a "PriorityQueue" data structure. It always stays sorted as you add/remove elements." ...."The timing of each "Push" is extremely small, around 5.*10^-7 on my machine. To get average push time:"  Sounds perfect for what I need for a high volume messaging application.  My guess is just use /:~ untll there is a "proven" need for something faster then code something like a priority queue in C and call from J.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search `I.` is the best you can do to find an element in a sorted array.

`[;.0` is the best you can do to extract a subarray.

These are very fast on their own:

```
y =: i.1e7
100 timespacex'y I. 35'
 2.94e_6 896
100 timespacex'(35 ,: _) ];.0 y'
 4.85e_6 1856
```

The bottleneck seems to be appending the new element thus copying the list to make the new list.

```
100 timespacex'35,~(35 ,: _) ];.0 y'
 0.0368233 1.3422e8


insert=: 4 : 0
 NB. insert x into ordered array y
 where=: x (< i. 1:) y
 z=: (($y)-where)|.(where|.y),x 
)

insert2=: 4 : 0
 where=: y I. x
 NB. z =: where ({.,x,}.) y
 z =: (where ];.0 y),x,((where ,: _) ];.0 y)
)

y =: i.1e7
(35 insert y) -: (35 insert2 y)
 1

100 timespacex'35 insert y'
 0.0745025 2.68437e8
100 timespacex'35 insert2 y'
 0.0738203 2.68437e8
```

Other, more complicated, ways may offer better results, depending on what you need and what kind of input you have.

Comment: fromJ SpecialCombinations: Execution In Place (EIP)
.
"J recognizes situations in which the argument is no longer needed after the verb has been executed, and performs those operations in place, creating the result in the same area occupied by the argument.

In-place execution requires a supporting verb and a suitable argument.

The verbs (among many others) that support in-place execution are:

x , y can append to x in place, provided its precision does not have to be changed."    Since the append of x to y should be in place perhaps the two rotates are slow?

Comment: The append is in place but rotate requires copying?

Comment: My guess: If the sorted array was a substring of a larger array ( to avoid copying) and a pointer kept for the end of that sorted array "and" it was possible to rotate a portion of that sorted array "in place" similar to the insert verb above, then it might be possible for an ultra rapid append into that  sorted 'sub" array.

Comment: An in-place operation has the form `name =: name , y`. If you can formulate your solution in this way, you will have the benefits of the in-place operation.

Comment: x=.?10000000$100    timespacex '<./ x'   0.0074838 1344  - just using an unsorted array and using <./ x to find smallest is blazing enough then with inplaced appending, should be easily fast enough.